# Disadvantages of cross entropy loss comparing to SVM loss

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, svm, cross-entropy

What are some disadvantages and limitations of the cross entropy loss, especially compared with SVM loss/hinge loss? I am just looking for a general idea of when would one use SVM loss over cross entropy. Thanks!